# App script display blank on google site, google calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-sites

I have this code and it has been working for months but all of a sudden it stopped working and I can't figure out why. It will display nothing when it is embedded on a google site.

```
function doGet() {

   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('220')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

This then should get the .html file in the same script labeled 220.I will show it below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Campus Center Calendar</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>

    var date = new Date(); 
    var year = date.getFullYear(); 
    var month = date.getMonth(); 
    month=month+1; 
    if (month < 10) 
    month = "0" + month; 
    var day= date.getDate(); 
    if (day < 10) 
    day = "0" + day; 
    var datestring=year+month+day;

    document.write('<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=mc817dld6jbb91lku4cei8h9n7eriqbl%40import.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York&amp;mode=DAY&amp;dates='+datestring+'%2F'+datestring+'&amp;showTz=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showCalendars=0" style="border-width:0" width="300" height="900" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"><\/iframe>');


    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

[Code picture (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEqtH.jpg)

[html picture (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4igt.jpg)

This is supposed to let me embed a app script to google sites and when this runs make a iframe with the calendar being displayed in day view with the current date.

THANK YOU FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I think that `dates` which is one of query parameters is the reason of your problem. In your script for retrieving the parameter of `dates`, when the month became October, the variable of month is used as a number. So for example, Oct. 6, 2017 becomes `202706`. This occurs an error. So your script doesn't work. When this is reflected to your script, please modify your script of `220.html` as follows.

#### From :

```
var datestring=year+month+day;
```

#### To :

```
var datestring = year + month.toString() + day.toString();
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.